# Weird height doubling bug on mouseover with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

i have used jquery and javascript to create some custom rollover button functionality and i am experiencing an issue where a variable is not be overwritten but added to. The basic function of my code is on mouseover of a link, i simply want the link to slide up and double in height so that the bottom 'on' portion of the graphic is showing (exactly like css sliding doors rollovers).

However the issue i am having is that the doubleHeight variable is cumulative so that every time you roll over the link the double height of the link is not reset each time, it just adds it to the last value. Weirdly this is only happening after a lightbox is triggered on the page, before that the functionality works just fine. Here is my javascript:

```
var heightVal, doubleHeight;

$('div.flex_rollover_btn p a').bind('mouseover', function() {
    heightVal = $(this).css('height');
    doubleHeight = heightVal.replace("px", "");
    doubleHeight = doubleHeight * 2 + "px";
    $(this).css({height: doubleHeight, top: '-' + heightVal});
});

$('div.flex_rollover_btn p a').bind('mouseout', function() {
    heightVal = $(this).parent().css('height');
    $(this).css({height: heightVal, top: '0'});
});
```

and here is the HTML code it is acting upon:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 322px; left: 13px; width: 139px; height: 79px; z-index: 3;" class="block item_3 flex_rollover_btn">
    <p style="width: 75px; height: 53px;"><a style="width: 75px; height: 53px;" class="new_window" title="Flexible Size Rollover Test 2" href="http://doctype.tv"><img height="106" width="75" alt="Flexible Size Rollover Test 2" src="/cms/arcadiacorp_uk/repository/pages/static/static-0000006614/images/flex_rollover_2.gif"></a></p>
</div>
```

To see it in action [go here](http://www.topshop.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CatalogNavigationSearchResultCmd?catalogId=33057&storeId=12556&langId=-1&viewAllFlag=false&categoryId=286989&interstitial=true) scroll to the right and mouse over the red star thing, then open a lightbox (any of the links with the + symbol next to them) close it and mouseover the red star thing again and you will see what i mean.

Comment: If you double the div.flex_rollover_btn height then the parent height will increase aswell (if it is not tall enough). So when you then get the parents height in the mouseout event the height will be the same as the doubled height. You'll need to store the previous height.

Comment: Hi Sani, this is what i tried:

$('div.flex_rollover_btn p a').mouseover(function() {
            heightVal = $(this).css('height');
   constantHeight = heightVal;
            doubleHeight = heightVal.replace("px", "");
            doubleHeight = doubleHeight * 2 + "px";
            $(this).css({height: doubleHeight, top: '-' + heightVal});
        });
        
        $('div.flex_rollover_btn p a').mouseout(function() {
            $(this).css({height: constantHeight, top: '0'});
        });

Is this what you meant, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In your mouseout handler function, you don't actually do anything. You get the heightVal (which was doubled earlier) and assign it back. The simple solution is to devide the value by two before assigning, just like you double it in the mouseover function.

The best way is to do it all with CSS classes. In CSS you specifiy all dimensions like height and then in JavaScript you can simply change the height by adding or removing a class.

Edit: I see in the mouseout handler function you look at the parent. Are you sure the parent isn't resized with the child element?

Comment: (S)he actually gets the parents height but that has doubled aswell.

Comment: Hi guys, the reason i get the parent height is because this p should always remain a constant height. I'm not sure why you think it is being doubled in height, i have used console.log to check the height of the p on mouseover and mouseout and both record the same value that has not changed.

N.B. i noticed that mouseover was firing multiple times, so i have switched to using mouseenter and mouseleave instead.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't directly addressing your question, but don't do this:

```
doubleHeight = heightVal.replace("px", "");
doubleHeight = doubleHeight * 2 + "px";
```

Instead, do this:

```
doubleHeight = (2 * parseInt(heightVal, 10)) + px;
```